# Can adwords api apps only be accessed by MCC linked accounts?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am looking at developing an app using the google adwords api.

I have found [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/signingup) that I need an MCC account to be able to access the google adwords API.

Does this mean that only people with adwords accounts linked to my MCC account can use my app?

Or can my app be accessed by anyone with an adwords account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app will be able to access any AdWords account provided the owner of that account allows it.

The AdWords account does not need to be linked to your MCC.

The user of your app will have to grant permission for your app to access their AdWords account before any calls to the AdWords API are made by your app.

Check [these docs on the OAuth2 flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) out for further details and then [these](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) for installed applications.